# Complement of a set of intervals

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, intervals

I have a set of intervals inside the range [0,k].

How can I produce the complement set of this set of intervals?

I can come up with an algorithm, but it requires sorting the intervals.

Therefore, the complexity is O(nlogn), where n is the number of intervals.

Is there any faster algorithm to do this? If not, is there any way to prove that this is the optimal complexity?

Thank you.

Comment: "prove it", prove what? Prove that there is a faster algorithm? Or prove that it isn't?

Comment: Note that if you sort the intervals, the complexity will be relative to the number of intervals, not relative to the maximum value `n`.  Moreover, it will not directly work if the intervals are overlapping.

Comment: @Damien Updated the question, I mistakenly used n for both notations. Thank you.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Updated the question with what I meant.

Comment: To be honest, I've tried to find a better algorithm myself and I couldn't. Obviously does not mean anything at all. The implementation I went for used a priority queue and thus ended up being, as you said, O(nlogn) for the whole shebang. My goal was to find distinct sections where no sub-intervals start or stop inside, but the solution was also used to find the complement set.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thank you for your reply. I am amazed that there is nothing online regarding this topic. I would at least expect to find some code online solving this problem...

Comment: In my understanding, you need implicit or explicit sort of something. So O(n logn). But a formal proof of it is never easy. For example, you need to estimate the hole between the first and second intervals, same for others... How to do it without sorting?

Comment: @Damien That's what we concluded as well, we felt we had no other way to do it optimally to first sort the intervals and then linearly process them one end at a time, which involved a priority queue. Our master-of-big-o figured out that it ended up being O(2*nlogn) which is equivalent to O(nlogn). However, considering that the naive implementations ran quite fast we didn't feel like it warranted more research on our side.

Comment: In practice, let us assume that you have an algorithm to do it in O(n). Then you can show that you have invented a new sort algorithm working in O(n). If `[a1 a2 ... an]` need to be sorted, then consider the intervals `[a1, a1+eps] [a2, a2 + eps] ... [an + eps]` when `eps` is smaller than all differencs ... The two problems are equivalent, therefore same complexity.

Comment: You might be interested by an [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree).

Comment: @Damien Would be good if you fleshed that out as an answer, including how to construct the sorted `[a1 a2 ... an]` from the result.

Comment: @KellyBundy I am not really a specialist, but I tried to detail it in an answer.

Answer (score 3):

In practice, let us assume that you have found an algorithm to perform this task (find the complement set) in O(n).

Then we can show that you have invented a new sort algorithm working in O(n).

To simplify, let us assume that the array to be sorted consists of natural numbers, and that there is no repetition.

If `[a1 a2 ... an]` need to be sorted, then consider the intervals `[a1, a1+1) [a2, a2 + 1) ... [an, an + 1)`.

Applying you algorithm to generate the complement set of intervals in O(n), we get `n` intervals

​   `[x1a + 1, x1b) [x2a + 1, x2b])... [xna + 1, xnb)`

where the `{xia, xib}` corresponds to successive `aj` elements after sorting.

Let us assimilate this relation as a directed edge in a graph, connecting the two vertices `xia` and `xib`.

To get the original array in sorted array, we need to find the start of the graph, and then walking through the graph, which can be done in O(n).

The sort has been performed in O(n).

The fact that we did not consider repetitions is not too annoying from a theoretical point of view, if we consider for example that with hashing, we can suppress the repetitions in O(n).

The fact to not consider floating point values is a detail: finding a new O(n) sort algorithm for natural numbers
would be already a great result.